# jquery insert value to another tags or attributes

Tags: jquery

I do like to create a code that will give the url from **REL** of **IMAGE** to **A href**. Is there are possible way of doing that ?

Here's what my idea was.

```
<img src="root/folder/image/path.jpg" rel="url-link.php">
```

then I do like to get the **REL** value and pass it to

```
<a href="url-link.php" target="_parent">
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like a really simple problem if you work with for a while.

Comment: Please only use attributes for what they were defined for. If you want to store custom data in an element, use the `data-*` attributes. Otherwise you're just writing non-semantic and invalid code.

Comment: yeah, although im not a developer or programmer that have a wide knowledge in jquery and other language...  :(  im still learning this library.  :)  and Thanks for the others.

Comment: @ahren, sorry about that, never know that.  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a').attr('href',$('img').attr('rel'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to do like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yaK25/)

```
​jQuery(document)​.ready(function(){
  var rel = jQuery('img').attr('rel');   
    jQuery('a').attr('href',rel);
  });​
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the `rel` attribute form your img:

```
var rel = $('#yourImg').attr('rel');
$('#yourATag').attr('href', rel);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var rel = $('img').attr('rel');
$('a').attr('href',rel);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the attribute using `.attr()`:

```
var $img = $('#your_img_tag');

var $a = $('<a />', {
    href: $img.attr('rel'),
    target: '_parent'
});
```